# as.character() within function doesn't work

Tags: r

newbie question:

I have a seemingly i simple problem, but I cannot solve it.
I want to use as.character() within a function. However it doesn't work.
The functioncall doesn't give an error, but nothing happens to the dataframe.
What am i doing wrong?

I also tried all variations using the walrus-operator :=  and curlycurly {{}}, but i am not sure if i need to use them.

anyone?

```
  DRUG_1 <- c(1, 4, 6, 2)
  DRUG_2 <- c("long", "short", "long", "medium")
  DRUG_3 <- c(2, 6, 1, 8)
  df <- data.frame(DRUG_1, DRUG_2, DRUG_3)
  #dataframe

  df <- df %>%  mutate(DRUG_1 = as.character(DRUG_1))   
  #this works
  
  TestFunction <- function(DATAFRAME, COLUMN) {
    DATAFRAME <- DATAFRAME %>% mutate(COLUMN = as.character(COLUMN))  }
  #function to automate the proces for multiple columns
  
  TestFunction(df, DRUG_1)
  #no error, but nothing happens to the dataframe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `{{}}` to wrap the `COLUMN` if we want to pass unquoted argument.  In addition, use `:=` if we want to evaluate the argument on the lhs

```
library(dplyr)
TestFunction <- function(DATAFRAME, COLUMN) {
   DATAFRAME %>%
      mutate({{COLUMN}} := as.character({{COLUMN}}))
 
  }
```

-testing

```
> str(TestFunction(df, DRUG_1))
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ DRUG_1: chr  "1" "4" "6" "2"
 $ DRUG_2: chr  "long" "short" "long" "medium"
 $ DRUG_3: num  2 6 1 8
```

Comment: thank you!  that was very helpful!  But you omitted the first part (where the mutated dataframe is stored).  How should I incorporate that part?

Comment: @user14930989 you meant `DATAFRAME <-`.  It is not needed.  You are using the function to return the output which you can assign it to a new object i.e. `dfnew <- TestFunction(df, DRUG_1)`